# CString format return weird character

Tags: c-strings

student1's name print out correctly "alice", but student2's name print out in "weird characters".

```
char * student;
student = "alice";

printf("student1 : %s\n", student);

CString student2;
student2 = "alice";

student = (char *)( LPCSTR )student2;
printf("student2:%s\n", student);
```

why after cast it with "(char *)( LPCSTR )" , it returns weird character instead ?

Comment: In your project settings, are you compiling with the character set Unicode, MBCS, or other?

Comment: Your question title is about `CString.Format`.  But you have removed `CString.Format` from your question!

Comment: CString is unicode string, can't be cast into ASCII string.

Comment: @DUJiaen:  Wrong.  Depending on project settings and include files, `CString` can represent single-byte, MBCS or Unicode character sets.  See  [template CStringT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx)

Comment: @DUJiaen:my bad, as previously I thought that using "CString.Format" resulted those weird characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this program worked for me.

However, that does not mean it is correct.
With MBCS, you typically use `_T` macros to be sure your strings are declared properly.

Here is my simple re-write of your code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlstr.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LPCSTR student = _T("alice");        // Use the provided LPCSTR type instead of char*.
    printf("student1 : %s\n", student);

    CString student2(_T("alice"));       // Initialize a CString with the _T macro

    student = (LPCSTR)student2;          // LPCSTR is typedef to char*. 
                                         // So you effectively had (char*)(char*)student2;
                                         // TypeCasting something twice to the same type is stupid.

    printf("student2:%s\n", student);
    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
student1 : alice
student2:alice
```